# Getting Metamask Error Message into web3.js DApp after user rejects transaction

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, message

I'm building a simple HTML/JavaScript front-end to interact with a Smart Contract using web3.js and MetaMask.

I have a function to call one of the methods in order to send a contribution to the Smart Contract, as follows:

```
function sendContribution() {
  let sendAmount = web3.utils.toBN(document.getElementById("contributionAmt").value);
  contractInstance.methods.contribute().send( {
    from: defaultAccount,
    value: sendAmount
  }).then (function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch (function (error){
    console.error(error);
    showMessage("alert alert-danger", error);
  });
```

The function works fine - when called it opens the MetaMask ethereum Window to allow me to approve the transaction and it processes the transaction without a problem.

However, if I "reject" the transaction in the MetaMask window I get two error messages in the console log, the first from MetaMask with the reason for the error, and the second from web3 with just a generic "Internal JSON-RPC Error":

[image: console.log]

As per the code above I am displaying any error message for the user but this is only displaying the generic web3 error and does not display the MetaMask message.

My question is how can I capture the MetaMask message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was my error or a bug in MetaMask or web3 that has now been fixed, but the error messages are all now coming through correctly...[image]